# Using variables within quotes in a script to map network drives

Tags: powershell

We're logging network drive mappings to a log file on our laptops. And I wanna make a script that takes these log files and maps the logged drives for the user.

Example log script:

```
K: -> \\server01\folder
Y: -> \\server02\publicfolder
```

I already have a partial script, but it looks like it doesn't work.

```
    $logfile | foreach {
    $log = $_ -split ' -> '
    # Write-Host $log[0]
    # Write-Host $log[1]
    $Networkpath = $log[1]
    $DriveLetter = $log[0] -replace ":*",""
    New-PSDrive -Name `"$($DriveLetter)`" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root `"$($Networkpath)`" -Persist -Scope Global
  }
```

When I run the above script, I'm getting errors "New-PSDrive : When you use the Persist parameter, the root must be a file system location on a remote computer.".
I'm assuming that this is because the quotes around the `$DriveLetter` and `$Networkpath` variables aren't handled correctly.

But I'm not sure how to do it properly. Been trying multiple solutions from Google, but none seem to work :(

Comment: Your variables are already strings - no need to "stringify" them... ```New-PSDrive -Name $DriveLetter -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $Networkpath -Persist -Scope Global```. And maybe log their values out to console so you can see what they look like - your log file might not be in the format you think it is...

Comment: Remove all backticks as `New-PSDrive -Name "$($DriveLetter)" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "$($Networkpath)" -Persist -Scope Global`.